# weblogic ear deployment error with nullpointerexception

Tags: weblogic

I'm trying to migrate my project from 12.1a weblogic to 12c and encountered error during ear deployment.
I have one ear module which contains two war submodules. during the process while I was trying to deploy ear:exploded artifact to weblogic 12c. I got nullpointer exception which related to **BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.getClassPersistenceContextRefs**

The error log is as follows:

> weblogic.management.DeploymentException:
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.throwAppException(BaseDeployment.java:132)
> at
> weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:244)
> at
> weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:66)
> at
> weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
> at
> weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:65)
> at
> weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:229)
> at
> weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:103)
> at
> weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:242)
> at
> weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:800)
> at
> weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1352)
> at
> weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:270)
> at
> weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:177)
> at
> weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:186)
> at
> weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
> at
> weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:47)
> at
> weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:681)
> at
> weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
> at
> weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
> at
> weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
> at
> weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
> at
> weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:655)
> at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)  at
> weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
> Blockquote

Caused By:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.getClassPersistenceContextRefs(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:1180)
> at
> weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.J2eeAnnotationProcessor.processJ2eeAnnotations(J2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:44)
> at
> weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.processJ2eeAnnotations(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:120)
> at
> weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.PojoAnnotationProcessorImpl.processJ2eeAnnotations(PojoAnnotationProcessorImpl.java:93)
> at
> weblogic.application.internal.flow.PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.processAnnotations(PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.java:304)
> at
> weblogic.application.internal.flow.PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.processPOJOsInModuleScopes(PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.java:229)
> at
> weblogic.application.internal.flow.PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.prepare(PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.java:73)
> at
> weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
> at
> weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
> at
> weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:241)
> at
> weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:66)
> at
> weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
> at
> weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:65)
> at
> weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:229)
> at
> weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:103)
> at
> weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:242)
> at
> weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:800)
> at
> weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1352)
> at
> weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:270)
> at
> weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:177)
> at
> weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:186)
> at
> weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
> at
> weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:47)
> at
> weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:681)
> at
> weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
> at
> weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
> at
> weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
> at
> weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
> at
> weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:655)
> at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)  at
> weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)

I've added several datasources in weblogic console and nothing else was added.

It would be great if somebody could help!

Comment: try and improve your question. put only the relevant error blocks, add some context and code as to what you are trying to do. format your errors using the editor formatting options. right now, the question is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Match up the jpa version of the server and your application . WebLogic defaults to jpa 2.0 check in your project facets the JPA version and update WebLogic runtime to have the same JPA version